# Transferring files via Binary mode in SFTP

Tags: aix, ftp, sftp

While using FTP we can use the option `bi` to transfer files in binary mode however I am unable to find similar option in SFTP. Please find my code snippet below..

```
fileTransferToDEST()
{
echo "mput $4/$1 $3/" | sftp -b - $SRV_USER@$DEST_IP
}

fileTransferToDEST $filename $logpathwithfilename $destinationpath $sourcepath

returnvalue=$?

if [ "$returnvalue" != "0" ]; then

                echo;echo "FTP : Failed while transfering"
                exit 2

fi
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH `sftp` supports the binary mode only. So it's implicit.

See also [How to transfer binary file in SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29226647/850848) (on Stack Overflow)